# The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types 'System.DateTime' and 'System.Object'. --Comparing Datetime linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

I am having and issue comparing two date range in linq. My view throws an exception

> The binary operator Equal is not defined for the types
>   'System.DateTime' and 'System.Object'. Please how do i fix this ?
>    Any help would be appreciated.

```
 public ViewResult List(SearchTerms search, int page = 1)
 {
        (from posts in repository.JobPosts
                               orderby posts.PostDate descending
                               select new
                               {
                                   Id = posts.Id,     
                                   ......
                               })
      .Where(x =>  ((search.PostedDateFrom.CompareTo(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)) != 0
                                  || (search.PostedDateTo.CompareTo(DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)) != 0)) ?
                                      x.PostDate >= search.PostedDateTo && x.PostDate <= search.PostedDateTo : x.PostDate !=null)
                                      )).....
}
```

My searchterm model.

```
 public class SearchTerms
    {
        public string searchText { get; set; }
        public string JobFunction { get; set; }
        public string JobIndustry { get; set; }
        public string jobType { get; set; }
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedDateFrom { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedDateTo { get; set; }
        public decimal MinSalary { get; set; }
        public string JobRegion { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated .

**Update**

below is my JobPost Model.

```
 public class JobPost
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string JobType { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string Industry { get; set; }
        public string JobFunction { get; set; }
        public string JobLevel { get; set; }
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }
        public DateTime JobExpiryDate { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your PostDate is of type DateTime?

Comment: @khlr Its of Datetime. Pls see my update above.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now.Date)`? `DateTime.Now.Date` doesn't contain time, there is nothing to truncate.

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova , before i added that , i received the error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties" . I searched online and was told the compare requires a nullable datetime data type. I was told to add that in order to achieve my requirement. So `DbFunctions.TruncateTime` is just the formality my real value is `DateTime.Now.Date` . please  how do i compare between two dates ?

Comment: Try DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now), if that doesn't work you can compare Year, Month and Day separately, like `!(search.PostedDateFrom.Year==DateTime.Now.Year && search.PostedDateFrom.Month==DateTime.Now.Month && search.PostedDateFrom.Day==DateTime.Now.Day)`. It's a bit verbose, but will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that DateTime.Compare to takes an argument of type DateTIme, but TruncateTime returns a nullable DateTime.  I think you have to cast the result from TruncateTime.

Comment: it returns another exception "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties" if don't pass the nullable datetime.

Comment: @NuruSalihu That is because DateTime.Now.Date has no real complement in SQL, so Entity Framework cannot construct a SQL query from it.  I would call DateTime.Now.Date outside the LINQ query, pull out Year, Month and Day, and compare those 3 in your LINQ query.